# c++ boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to do a simple program:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

class Config {
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
....
```

But I am getting the error in the title above.

I am using the boost version **1.38**. Is it not in this version?

Comment: [Version 1.38.0
February 8th, 2009 12:00 GMT](http://www.boost.org/users/history/)

Comment: @sehe I don't get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/), property tree was added to boost in 1.41.0

You have to update your boost